# Since matter and energy are interchangable and elements naturally decay into energy does energy naturally decay into matter?

Tags: energy, radiation, big-bang, matter

Matter decays into energy in the form of radiation. Does this happen in reverse with energy collapsing back into matter naturally in our universe (the theory that this is what happened in the big bang excluded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the equation

$$E = mc^2$$

we can see that energy and mass are equivalent (with a constant $c^2$ factor). We can also see that a small amount of mass can create a huge amount of energy. This mass to energy conversion happens on a daily basis, like in nuclear reactors or the sun, as examples.

What is also apparent is the fact that you would need a huge amount of energy to do the opposite. That is, convert energy to mass. This happens in certain particle interactions.

[Pair production](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) is a process where energy (in the form of a photon) creates matter in the form of a particle and antiparticle. For example, an electron and a positron or a muon and an antimuon. But in order for such a process to occur, the energy of the incoming photon must be above a certain energy. Specifically, at least the total [rest mass energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) of the two particles, for example $2m_{e}c^2$, $2m_{\mu} c^2$ etc *and* only if the interaction is such that the energy-momentum is conserved.

The way the question is posed, sort of asks if energy can become mass easily, or if it happens in nature spontaneously. The answer is no, and as far as I know this does not happen in nature, unless the sun or other heavenly bodies allow highly energetic photonic or exotic processes that can. You (and other readers)  can research this, but as an example, the most energetic processes in the universe, come in the form of [gamma ray bursts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst) where (as per the article)

*In gamma-ray astronomy, gamma-ray bursts (GRBs) are extremely energetic explosions that have been observed in distant galaxies...The intense radiation of most observed GRBs is thought to be released during a supernova or superluminous supernova as a high-mass star implodes to form a neutron star or a black hole.*

But in that Wiki page on GRBs, there is no direct statement/observation/experiment (and I must admit I did just glance over it - please comment if you see otherwise) that the process $\gamma \rightarrow e^+ + e^-$ results from these GRBs, but there would be interactions where the photons produced by the GRBs can be scattered by electrons in the area surrounding the burst, and their interaction with other photons will create $e^+ e^-$ pairs (again assuming the photon energy in the centre‐of‐mass frame exceeds $2 \times mc^2$, where here $m$ is the electronic mass). In fact, doing a quick google search, there are some researchers who have found "electron-positron winds" resulting from GRBs. If you are interested, there is a Harvard paper [here](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ApJ...825..107G/abstract) from The Astrophysical Journal.

And at the [Big Bang](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) what we do know was that it was followed by accelerated expansion, prior to which all there was an extremely dense and energetic singularity, that became all of the mass and energy (and spacetime) in the universe. This is in fact an example of “energy turning into matter”.

Comment: though the equation is used now only when the mass m is at rest,  ( if there is a velocity. m depends on velocity and this brings a lot of unnecessary confusions)

Comment: Yes this is true. Let’s agree to keep it simple! :)